# If $m > 0$ and $A^m = I$, then $\lambda = \pm 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix. Let $\lambda \in \Bbb R$ be a an eigenvalue of $A$. Show that if $m > 0$ and $A^m = I$, then $\lambda = \pm 1$.

---

Can anyone give me tips on how to solve this question? So far, I have used the fact that $Au = λu$ and am not sure how to proceed from there.
I have also cited that depending on if $m$ is odd/even it will lead to $\lambda = \pm 1$ which I am not entirely sure if it is correct.

Comment: What are the possible nth real roots of unity?

Comment: What are the eigenvalues of $A^k$, for general $k$?

Comment: Sorry @Shahab I dont understand what you are saying

Comment: @catherine It would be det(λI - $A^k$) I would say

Comment: @drago An $n$th root of unity is some number $x$ such that $x^n = 1$. If $Au = \lambda u$, then $A^2 u = A Au = A \cdot \lambda u = \lambda Au$... Can you go further?

Comment: What real numbers $\lambda$ satisfy $\lambda^m=1$?

Comment: @catherine I can go towards $λ^m$ u is what I'm thinking

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts only ±1, but how do I prove that

Comment: I got it, thanks everyone